# Reuse assembly in other assemblies

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, typhoon

I'm trying to integrate typhoon into my project.

I have three classes, DBManager, ProductDataManager, and CustomerDataManager. Both ProductDataManager and CustomerDataManager depend on DBManager for db operation.

```
@interface ProductDataManager ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;
@end

@implementation ProductDataManager

- (instancetype)initWithDBManager:(DBManager*)dbManager
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dbManager = dbManager;
    }
    return self;
}


@interface CustomerDataManager ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;
@end

@implementation CustomerDataManager

- (instancetype)initWithDBManager:(DBManager*)dbManager
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dbManager = dbManager;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now I create three assemblies for them.

```
@interface DBManagerAssembly ()

@end

@implementation DBManagerAssembly

- (DBManager *)dbManager {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[DBManager class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        }];
        definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
    }];
}






@interface CustomerDataManagerAssembly ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManagerAssembly *dbManagerAssembly;
@end

@implementation CustomerDataManagerAssembly

- (CustomerDataManager *)customerDataManager {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[CustomerDataManager class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithDBManager:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self.dbManager];
        }];
    }];
}

- (DBManager *)dbManager {
    return [self.dbManagerAssembly dbManager];
}





@interface ProductDataManagerAssembly ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManagerAssembly *dbManagerAssembly;
@end

@implementation ProductDataManagerAssembly

- (ProductDataManager *)productDataManager {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ProductDataManager class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithDBManager:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self.dbManager];
        }];
    }];
}

- (DBManager *)dbManager {
    return [self.dbManagerAssembly dbManager];
}
```

Activate them in AppDelegate

```
- (NSArray *)initialAssemblies
{
    return @[[DBManagerAssembly class], [ProductDataManagerAssembly class], [CustomerDataManagerAssembly class]];
}
```

But on app startup, it throws an exception

```
[NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Key '%@' is already registered.", _definition.key];
```

My question is... how to reuse assembly properly and avoid exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typhoon allows you to create logical groupings of the key architectural actors in your system. This feature is called [Assembly Modularization](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Modularizing-Assemblies). All of the components defined go into a single `TyphoonComponentFactory` - which contains recipes for emitting built instances.

[image: assembly modules]

Before activation the assembly returns definitions. At runtime you can use the assembly as a facade to return built instances. It uses Objective-C message forwarding to resolve method calls to `[factory componentForKey:theMethodName]`. Therefore:

- Each component in the entire set of assemblies must have a unique name.

In your code, you've defined:

```
- (DBManager *)dbManager {
    return [self.dbManagerAssembly dbManager];
}
```

Remove this definition, and edit `customerDataManager` to instead have:

```
[initializer injectParameterWith:[self.dbManagerAssembly dbManager]];
```

All will be well.

Comment: Thank you, this answer did solve my problem.  It seems that I have to trace the source code for understanding the mechanism underneath.

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully you don't have to read the source unless you want to do that. There's a few rules and usage constraints to know though. Here's some more info on how Typhoon works under the hood: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/TyphoonAssembly